# Indy 10.6.0.5169 + OpenSSL 1.0.2u + Delphi XE7, handshake error

Tags: delphi

I would like to get data from a website using Indy, but its not working.
I get the following error:

> Error connecting with SSL.
> error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Here is the code:

```
var
  AMS: TMemoryStream;
begin
  AMS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    IdHTTP1.Get('https://www.optionsprofitcalculator.com/ajax/getStockPrice?stock=hca&reqId=0', AMS);
    AMS.SaveToFile('c:\test.txt');
  finally
    FreeAndNil(AMS);
  end;
end;
```

And the components:

```
object IdHTTP1: TIdHTTP
  IOHandler = IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1
  AllowCookies = True
  HandleRedirects = True
  ProxyParams.BasicAuthentication = False
  ProxyParams.ProxyPort = 0
  Request.Connection = 'keep-alive'
  Request.ContentLength = -1
  Request.ContentRangeEnd = -1
  Request.ContentRangeStart = -1
  Request.ContentRangeInstanceLength = -1
  Request.Accept = 
    'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp' +
    ',*/*;q=0.8'
  Request.AcceptEncoding = 'gzip, deflate, br'
  Request.AcceptLanguage = 'hu-HU,hu;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3'
  Request.BasicAuthentication = False
  Request.UserAgent = 
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101' +
    ' Firefox/77.0'
  Request.Ranges.Units = 'bytes'
  Request.Ranges = <>
  HTTPOptions = [hoForceEncodeParams]
  Left = 110
  Top = 155
end
object IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL
  MaxLineAction = maException
  Port = 0
  DefaultPort = 0
  SSLOptions.Method = sslvSSLv23
  SSLOptions.SSLVersions = [sslvSSLv2, sslvSSLv3, sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2]
  SSLOptions.Mode = sslmUnassigned
  SSLOptions.VerifyMode = []
  SSLOptions.VerifyDepth = 0
  Left = 155
  Top = 155
end
```

I have no clue where the problem is. If it cannot be achieved with Indy, I would like to know if there is any standard Delphi component to communicate with HTTPS servers?

Comment: where did you get the OpenSSL DLL from? the only official source is https://github.com/IndySockets/OpenSSL-Binaries atm

Comment: You should upgrade your Indy version: https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy

Comment: whorsdaddy: Im not sure tried half dozen different version. Tried your too, not working, cannot load SSL library.

Comment: zed: thanks, but I have no clue how to update using these source codes.

Comment: @tcxbalage "*I have no clue how to update using these source codes*" - see http://ww2.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.EN.aspx  10.6.0 is old, the current version is 10.6.2.

Comment: @tcxbalage "*I would like to know if there is any standard Delphi component to communicate with HTTPS servers*" - not in XE7, no. XE8 introduced [`THTTPClient`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Net.HttpClient.THTTPClient).

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: thanks for the instruction how to update the indy, but Im still confused. Downloaded the source, then I should run the "FULLD#.BAT" where # is the relevant Delphi version, there is no such file. I found "FULLC#.BAT", but that is for the C++ version.

Comment: @tcxbalage Indy stopped using `.BAT` scripts for Delphi after D2009.  Just compile the 5 package projects directly in the IDE instead, like the [instructions](http://ww2.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.EN.aspx) say (you can use the `Indy210.groupproj` project group for XE7 for that).

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: thanks again for the quick response. I'll try soon and let you know the result.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: So I finished the install. When starting IDE getting invalid entry point error (@Idstackwindows@TIdstackwindows@NetwokToHostSqqrj couldn't be located at IndySystem210.bpl) and an other error too (can't load dclMetropolisUILiveTile210.bpl). Im skipping these errors, compile and run my test project and then still getting the originan SSL error message.

Comment: @tcxbalage the LiveTile error is documented in the [instructions](http://ww2.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.EN.aspx): "*Embarcadero's Metropolis UI LiveTile framework is compiled against the Indy 10 packages that ship with the IDE.  Installing a new version of Indy will render LiveTiles unusable, as it will not be able to load the Indy packages anymore, and LiveTiles cannot be recompiled by end users.*" But if you are still getting OpenSSL errors, then the problem is with OpenSSL itself, or more likely with the particular settings/certificates you are using with it.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: yepp, you right, I found your notes, disabled Live Tiles package, sorry.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: any thoughts about the handshake failure error? Should I try to use different libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll files?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217106/discussion-between-tcxbalage-and-remy-lebeau).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mystery solved.

The mentioned site using TLS 1.3 which not supported by the Indy, yet.

Thanks to [Remy Lebeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau), who helped me in this investigation.

Comment: So what was the solution? Will this issue be resolved in the new version? @tcxbalage

Comment: Indy components can't be used in this case, bought SecureBridge.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by [Remy Lebeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau);

I am using **NetHttpClient**. It uses the operating system's SSL. If you do not have to use Indy, you can use this component.

```
var
   Stream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
   NetHTTPClient1.Get('https://www.optionsprofitcalculator.com/ajax/getStockPrice?stock=hca&reqId=0', Stream);
   Stream.SaveToFile('c:\test.txt');
  finally
    FreeAndNil(Stream)
  end;
```

You can try it this way. I tested it and it works.

Comment: thanks, but as I mentioned in the title Im using XE7.

Comment: @HalilHanBadem `TNetHttpClient` was introduced in XE8.