# JIRA query using Delphi XE7 + SecureBridge

Tags: delphi, jira, devart

I try to retrieve some information from our JIRA (cloud) using TScHttpWebRequest component.
The RequestUri is set to

"https://takarekinfo.atlassian.net/rest/agile/1.0/issue/KE-7347?fields=customfield_10274".

Filled the component Credentils properties, but it says "Unauthorized".
As I understand the JIRA wont accept basic authentication anymore, so I generated a token and tried this:

"https://takarekinfo.atlassian.net/rest/agile/1.0/issue/KE-7347?user=my_email@domain.com:xxxx_my_token_xxx&fields=customfield_10274".

Still no luck.
If I log in to the JIRA in the browser both URL working fine.
Unfortunatelly I have very little knowledge about this kind of technology, so I would appreciate any help how can I retrieve the desired information form our JIRA.

update:
this one is working fine with curl.exe:
curl.exe -D- -u my_email@domain.com:xxxx_my_token_xxx -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://takarekinfo.atlassian.net/rest/agile/1.0/issue/KE-7347?fields=customfield_10274

All I need to implement this code using SecureBridge or other working solution under XE7. Tried TIdHTTP, not working for me, it says IOHandler not assigned and when I assign a SSL IOHandler says SSL library could not load, probably this is the same problem I ran into, Indy doesnt handle certain SSL protocols.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is not appropriate to edit a solution into the question itself. If you've found a solution and want to share it, do so by writing an answer in the space provided below for that purpose. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more information.

Comment: You can use Indy SSL, but need to distribute the OpenSSL libraries to actually make it work: https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/Archive/

Comment: @R.Hoek, i know, but this is a different problem, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62579768/indy-10-6-0-5169-openssl-1-0-2u-delphi-xe7-handshake-error

Comment: @tcxbalage yes, I know there are issues depending on the Indy version and required ssl version, but that wasn’t clear in the question ;)

Comment: @R.Hoek, you right I didnt specify clearly the problem about the Indy, was lazy to type that much, sorry :),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

TScHttpWebRequest.HeaderText= 'authorization=Basic FFFFFFFF'

where FFFFFFFF is the base64 encoded 'my_email@domain.com:xxxx_my_token_xxx'

Comment: This is basic HTTP knowledge - see [RFC 7617](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7617) and/or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), which means your assumption "As I understand the JIRA wont accept basic authentication anymore" was wrong.

Comment: @AmigoJack, basic authentication means user+password, which is not allowed on JIRA, only user+token.

Comment: I have no permission to access the JIRA ticket, so "token" still looks to me just like password rules and cannot be distinguished from a password technically. https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/basic-authentication/ nowhere mentions tokens instead of passwords.

Comment: The page that you linked is referring to the Jira server which you can download and install for yourself. I have problem with the Jira cloud, as I mentioned in my question. There are different security rules, username+password not allowed.

Comment: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/deprecation-notice-basic-auth-and-cookie-based-auth/

Comment: In Jira terms yes: you (now) must use a token, not a password. But it is still a HTTP basic authentication as per RFC and there it is irrelevant how "password" looks like. https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloud/api-tokens-938839638.html confirms that it is still a HTTP basic authentication - your problem is unbound to any HTTP context, as talking with Jira has not changed in your code - only your "password" has changed.